# Critical section not working

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have this main form

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)    
  fReceiver: TMessageReceiver;
  fCS: TCriticalSection;  
  constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent); override; **Create Critcal section**
  destructor Destroy(); override; **Delete critical section**
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fcs.Acquire;
  //Perform Action
  fcs.Release;

end;

TMessageReceiver= class(TReceiver)
  private
    fFrame: TForm1;
  public
    constructor Create(aFrame: TForm1);
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    function HandleMessage(aUserName: string): boolean; override;
  end;

 function TMessageReceiver.HandleMessage(aUserName: string): boolean;
 begin
   fFrame.fcs.Acquire;
    //Do Lengthy OP
   fFrame.fcs.Release;
 end;
```

I have this two classes where TMessageReceiver is called in a thread. I try to synchronize between these two classes. After calling handle message if i try to click the button it is getting inside the critical section block eventhough it is already aquired in HandleMessage.
I dont know what is wrong with this code.

Any suggestions would be of immense help.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you showed, so it has to be a problem with code you did not show. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Code seems OK. You do not let us see the Create from the TMessageReceiver. So a question pop up: is it the same critical section or are there multiple form1 instances around and hence multiple cirtical sections?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It is a very big code so i dont know how to show it. To simplify things i removed all the usage of critical section and having it only in button click and removed the release. Now when i click the button twice it is entering the block even though i am not releasing it. why is it so?

Comment: @RitsaertHornstra: I put a debug point in constructor and destructor of form 1 instance and it is called once. Is there any way i can determine if there are multiple instance of critical section?

Comment: @Jeeva: I wasn't asking for your entire code, just a small [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the same issue. As for the rest, when a thread has already gained ownership of the CS's lock, it can re-enter the same CS as many times as it wants. The only requirement is that each Acquire must have a Release to keep the CS's internal lock counter balanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible explanations for a call to `Acquire` succeeding.

1. The critical section is unowned.
2. The critical section is owned by the calling thread.

You can use the `DebugInfo` field of the critical section struct to check the recursion count: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc164040.aspx

A possible cause for option 1, the critical section not being owned, is that you created multiple critical section instances.

The likely cause for option 2 is that all your code runs in the same thread.

We cannot give you much more detailed diagnosis because you removed all the essential detail from the question. This is a classic situation where an SSCCE would help everybody.

---

Looking at your code more broadly, it shows worrying signs. In `TMessageReceiver.HandleMessage` you acquire a critical section and set about performing a lengthy operation. But then in `TForm1.Button1Click`, an input event handler, you attempt to claim the same critical section. If you do that whilst the lengthy operation is in progress, you will block the UI thread. You will have a non-responsive UI and likely Windows will mark your window as non-responsive and ghost it.

It is very surprising to see a critical section acquired in an input event handler. That has all the symptoms of being a major design flaw.

Comment: I think you are correct. Digging deep through the code it seems the messagereceiver is not a thread but a event handler. So i think it is in the same thread. Now should i use some other mechanism to synchronize like events?

Comment: If it is in the same thread it should not be able to execute at the same time twice. Unless you have Application.ProcessMessages called somewhere. You can check whih thread it is by calling get GetCurrentThreadId

Comment: If all your code runs on the same thread, then why do you need synchronization?

Comment: @David, I suspect because he is trying to hide the true problem with it. He is probably calling ProcessMessages somewhere. This could explain the issue, especially because he said that this is an event and as such it is possible that it notifies via PostMessage and then ProcessMessages at the wrong place can cause this.

Answer (score 2):

A critical section ensures that no other threads enter the protected section of code at the same time, it does not protect against re-entrance from the same thread. That means if from anywhere within the protected section of code you happen to call `Application.ProcessMessages` you can easily get re-entrance problems. Just a guess though...

Comment: It is a good guess. I can't see any other way for it to happen.